# Upload .mp3 file in Google Cloud Storage using Java client JSON API

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine

Is it possible to upload a mp3 file (audio file) in Google Cloud Storage  using Java client library.

I can access my bucket from Cloud Storage and can read the content of my bucket using Java client library JSON API.

If it is possible can anyone please refer a url path from where I can start or get an idea to upload mp3 file.

Comment: try this https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-java-samples

Comment: Thanks Igor for reply. In this example they show how to upload txt file (content-type=text/plain) in bucket. If i am not wrong, for mp3 file, content type is audio/mpeg. But i could not understand how i read mp3 file for InputStreamContent ? Can you please give me an idea ?

Comment: just create InputStream from a file, byte[] or anything. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html

Comment: Thank you Igor. Now its midnight. I will try your solution on Monday morning and will update the post